# Im new to unity and in was coding until i ran into a problem the math could not apply to the string to update the score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

+=100 is not working. I tried but nothing helped. If someone knows the answer please post.

Error: Assets\Scripts\playerController.cs(61,50): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '+='

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);  


        scoreText.text = scoreText.ToString((scoreText += 1));


    }
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
    {
        Destroy(Player);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `scoreText`? What is your goal with this code? Do you want to actually modify `scoreText` inside the `ToString` or just add 1 to whatever would be displayed? When you say "not working" is isn't super helpful in troubleshooting the issue. Can you give some more details about that along with any errors you're receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you aiming for is something like this

```
int scoreCount = 0;
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);  

        scoreCount += 1;
        scoreText.text = scoreCount.toString();

    }
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
    {
        Destroy(Player);
    }
}
```

You have tried to edit a Textfield with an Integer sum functionality which cant be working, you basically try to edit an string with +1. Maybe Im wrong but for a more detailed answer I need more details in the question.

Comment: Really helped i just needed to change it from "toString();" to "ToString();".